# python 3.4.3 asyncio async in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, asynchronous, python-3.4, python-asyncio

I'm trying to start an async process to process some images using async from asyncio in eclipse with python 3.4.3. The lines are:

```
for img in images:
    tasks.append(asyncio.async(process_images(img)))
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

I've already import the asyncio and the program can run successfully. But I still got the red line under async, and an problem shows:

```
Encountered "async" at line 37, column 38. Was expecting:     <NAME> ...
```

wonder what this means and how to make it right.

Comment: Wild guess: Eclipse is using 3.5 semantics, in which [async is a keyword](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/).  Try using [`asyncio.ensure_future()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future) instead.  Note that this requires 3.4.4.

Comment: Thank you kevin, but just one more thing, the sleep in asyncio.sleep(1) is also underlined. Is sleep also a keyword?

Comment: @YishaYi No, `sleep` is not a keyword. It sounds like maybe Eclipse is just having trouble resolving the `asyncio` package correctly. Does it underline *all* methods in the `asyncio` module?

Comment: @dano No. For my project, the `sleep` and `async` are underlined but the `wait` is not underlined